# Is it possible to attach UITapGestureRecognizer to UILabel subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

I'm trying to attach gesture recognizer to my own class which is subclass of UILabel, but it does not work. Can you help me to understand what's wrong in the code

```
 
@interface Card : UILabel  {

}

- (void) addBackSideWord;

@end

#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addBackSideWord)];
        [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
        [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) addBackSideWord {

     //do something
}
@end
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your code should work fine, the only thing you may need to fix is that user interaction is disabled for UILabel by default, so gesture recogniser does not receive any touch events. Try manually enable it by adding this line to your code (e.g. in init method):

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I spent 24 hours reading documentation and did not note this simple trick. Just hope it was useful for me:)

Answer (score 16):

**Yes, that's possible,** Any class **inherited** from `UIView`.

**Do'nt forget to enable user interaction.**

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I spent 24 hours reading documentation and did not note this simple trick. Just hope it was useful for me:)

Comment: @Michael :Happen sometime .. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to add tap gesture on UILable :-

Step 1:

```
 Delegate "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate" to your viewcontroller.h

 for example:
     @interface User_mail_List : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Step 2:

```
//create you UILable
UILabel *title_lbl= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
[title_lbl setText:@"u&me"];
[title_lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[yourView addSubview:title_lbl];
```

Step 3:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap= [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Prof_lbl_Pressed:)];//your action selector
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
title_lbl.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
[title_lbl addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Step 4:

```
-(void)Prof_lbl_Pressed:(id)sender{
    //write your code action
}
```

thanks,