# How to clickable UILabel's Text

Tags: uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, nsrange

I want to make some text clickable in uilabel.

Here is the text where Privacy Policy and Terms of Service should be click-able.

> By tapping to continue you are indicating that you have read the
>   Privacy Policy and agree to the Terms of Service.

Can any one help me!!!!

Comment: It's easier to have a transparent `UIButton` over it.

Comment: yeah,bt want to learn uitapgesturerecognizer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to attach UITapGestureRecognizer to UILabel subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355650/is-it-possible-to-attach-uitapgesturerecognizer-to-uilabel-subclass)

Comment: and also want to open two different screen on tapping Privacy Policy and Terms of Service

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NSAttributedString` for your purpose.

Add URL Link to **"Privacy Policy"** and **"Terms of Service"** text and on click on any particular text you can perform any action you want.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630187/1223897) answer for more help.